# How to unstack the first row index in the Multidex in Pandas

Tags: pandas

in pandas I have a dataframe using unstack()like follows with

```
              mean                  median                std
              0    1    2   3       0    1    2    3      0     1     2    3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2019-08-31   2    3    6   4       3    3    2    3      0.3  0.4    2    3
```

before the unstack(),the frame is :

```
                    mean    median   std
--------------------------------------------
2019-08-31  0       2       3         0.3
            1       3       3         0.4
            2       6       2         2
            3       4       3         3

2019-09-01  0
```

which unstack() command can I use to remove the the first row index and make the frame like:

```
              0    1    2   3       0    1    2    3      0     1     2    3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2019-08-31   2    3    6   4       3    3    2    3      0.3  0.4    2    3
```

Comment: This is just removing a level from the columns `MultiIndex`. But before you do that, why? Now you have a duplicated Index and it's very error prone to now figure out which column was `('mean', 0)` as opposed to `('std', 0)`

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()`

Comment: `df.unstack(level=0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from your original instruction:

```
df = df.unstack()
```

This instruction actually unstacks *level=-1* i.e. the **last** level
of the MultiIndex and adds it to the column index.

Then run:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

which actually drops *level=0* i.e. the **top** level of MultiIndex
(just *mean / median / std*).